Model looks dented but geometry is correct
I'm wondering why my model has weird artifacts. I already tried removing overlapping vertices, and recalculating normals. I've attached the blender file to the post



In Mesh section of Properties window in Geometry Data section, click on Clear Custom Split Normals Data:


Thank you so much!

You have bad split normals on some of your vertices:

You need to fix your normals. Easiest is to clear the splits, using:
Properties > Object Properties > Geometry Data > Clear Custom Split Normals Data

Once you do that:


Thank you so much!

Love it.  Same information as the currently accepted answer...but also explains what's going on with explanations and visuals.  Thank you.
